# Select2 doesn't run on 'append'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

Select2 function doesn't open on appending new select tag, and console has this error (Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function).

```
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">   </script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js'></script>

$(document).on('click', '#addNewItem', function() {
      var a = $(".gh").val();
      a++;
      $('.asd').append('<select class="form-control select2" name="ProposalItemName[]">' +
        '<optgroup label="Items">' +
        '<option>test</option>' +
        '<option>test</option>' +
        '</optgroup>' +
        '</select>');
      $('.select2').select2();
    });
```

Comment: if you want select2(); function to run, just use select2(); instead of $('.select2').select2();

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: works for me https://jsfiddle.net/cx5m40wu/1/

Comment: you have 2 jquery files that are the same, remove one of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/cx5m40wu/2/

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addNewItem', function() {
  var a = $(".gh").val();
  a++;
  $('.asd').append(`<select class="form-control select2" name="ProposalItemName[]">
    <optgroup label="Items">
      <option>test</option>
      <option>test</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>`);
  $('.select2').select2();      
});
```

```css
.alignRight{
  float: right;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<div class="asd">
  test
</div>
<button id="addNewItem" type="button">
Click
</button>
```

I believe the issue in your code is 2 `jQuery`.

> Check the order of `JavaScript` & `CSS` files.

I've used `ES6` standard (template literals)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What a perfect solution. It still helped a lot in 2020. Thank you.